# How come when we pick up a baby or first reaction is to rock them, even if you have never ever held a baby before?

Tags: behavior, adult-child

My mother just had a baby girl yesterday and I have always been the youngest so I have never held a baby before until yesterday. When I held her for the first time yesterday my immediate instinct was to start bouncing her softly/ bobbing her up and down. I started talking with my mom and wanted to know why it is the human beings instinct when holding a baby?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't instinctive. Many new parents have difficulty learning how to rock and hold babies.

Generally, though, most people learn it through behaviours through their childhood.

An odd quirk, though, is that babies often like to be rocked faster than the person holding them would expect - we first encountered this when we became parents: our kids liked being rocked nearly twice as fast as I would have thought comfortable, but after asking people and searching online this seems the norm.

Comment: It is indeed true. Some kids like to be rocked in a manner I would call 'violent rocking' (I don't advocate it, though.) This is especially true of babies of mothers who were very active during the entire pregnancy, for example, runners. When you think that a baby probably slept while its mother was running, you can well imagine a gentle rocking will not suffice. :)